# Domain controller on different network

Tags: networking, domain

I have following problem:
On my network I have two networks. Lets say Network 1 and Network 2. Each network has a Router with an internet connection, the routers have static Routes pointing to each others network and there is a router connecting the two networks together, acting as a gateway.

---

Network 2 has an AD DS, DNS etc setup working, whereas in Network 1 the internet router acts as a DNS, DHCP... server. So my question is, how can I add computers from Network 1 to the domain (in Network 2). So the computers from the Network 1 will still connect to the internet through their router, but the whole ADDS stuff should be handled by the other gateway router (pointing to Network 2). I hope my description was understandable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Computers in Network 1 will need to use the domain controllers in Network 2 for DNS. Alternatively, the DNS server in Network 1 can have a conditional forwarder for the AD domain in Network 2 to forward requests for the AD domain to Network 2.

Comment: Can I do it somehow on each PC? Fritzbox 7590 doesn't seem to be able to do that. Is there another simple ish solution?

Comment: @BobBerg: most DHCP servers can specify the DNS servers to use.

Comment: Disable the dhcp on Fritz and setup the dhcp on the dc